# C#のJITコンパイラの最適化で、この比較の実行回数はどうなりますか？

Tags: c#

以下のように静的な読み取り専用のフィールド作った場合、Testメソッドの`CONST == 10` の部分はJITコンパイラの最適化によって1度だけ実行されるのでしょうか。それともTestメソッドが呼び出される度に比較が行われるのでしょうか。

```cs
class MainClass
{
   static readonly int CONST = 10;

   static void Main()
   {
      for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         Test();
   }

   static int Test()
   {
      if(CONST == 10)
         return 100;
      else
         return 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

一度も実行されません。`Test()`は`100`を返すとみなされ、更にインライン展開されます。質問文のコードでは`Test()`を呼ぶ意味がないため空のループが回ります。

---

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(Test());
```

で生成されたネイティブコードを確認します。

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
00007FFB7CB65F2A  xor         esi,esi  
00007FFB7CB65F2C  mov         rcx,7FFB7CC02BD8h  
00007FFB7CB65F36  mov         edx,1  
00007FFB7CB65F3B  call        CORINFO_HELP_GETSHARED_NONGCSTATIC_BASE (07FFBDC6BA540h)  
            Console.WriteLine(Test());
00007FFB7CB65F40  cmp         dword ptr [7FFB7CC02C0Ch],0Ah  
00007FFB7CB65F47  jne         MainClass.Main()+030h (07FFB7CB65F50h)  
00007FFB7CB65F49  mov         ecx,64h  
00007FFB7CB65F4E  jmp         MainClass.Main()+035h (07FFB7CB65F55h)  
00007FFB7CB65F50  mov         ecx,1  
00007FFB7CB65F55  call        CLRStub[MethodDescPrestub]@7ffb7cb65ed8 (07FFB7CB65ED8h)  
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
00007FFB7CB65F5A  inc         esi  
00007FFB7CB65F5C  cmp         esi,64h  
00007FFB7CB65F5F  jl          MainClass.Main()+020h (07FFB7CB65F40h)
```

`MOV ECX,64h` となっていて、これが`Console.WriteLine()`に渡されています。つまり`Test()`メソッドは定数値`64h`を返すとみなされています。
（`Console.WriteLine(Int32)`オーバーロードが素直に呼ばれていないところを見ると、`Console.WriteLine()`側もインライン展開されていそうです。）